# How to use as_hms in a for loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, timestamp

I have multiple csv files with the columns "timestamp" and "users_holding" I was able to split the timestamp column into two columns "Date" and "Time". I am now trying to round up the Time column for each file. After rounding up I want to recombine the two columns again and remove any double rows. The code for one file is as followed:

```
    data <- separate(data = data, col = timestamp, into  = c('Date', 'Time'), sep = ' ')
as_hms(data$Time)
data$Time <- round_hms(as_hms(data$Time), 60*60)
data$timestamp <- paste(data$Date,data$Time)
data <- data[!duplicated(data$timestamp), ]
```

A coded a for loop to separate the columns. However I am not able to build the code for the other steps. My current code is as followed:

```
    #Separate all timestamps into Date and Time
files <- list.files(pattern = "*csv")
df_list <- lapply(files,read_csv)
df <- bind_rows(df_list)

st_datasets <- df_list
updated_datasets_st <- list()
for (i in 1:length(st_datasets)){
  d <- st_datasets[[i]] %>% separate(col = timestamp, into  = c('Date', 'Time'), sep = ' ')
  updated_datasets_st[[i]] <- d
}
#need help for this part. The code above is working
for (i in 1:length(st_datasets)){
  d <- st_datasets[[i]] %>% round_hms(as_hms(st_datasets$Time), 60*60)
  updated_datasets_st[[i]] <- d
}
```

Comment: Can you include a small sample of the data you're working with? Something like `dput(head(data, 20))`

Comment: I made some data, but I'm not able to find an issue using the data I made, so it's something specific to your data or, more likely, your data structure. For example, with the `flights` data from the package `nycflights13`: `flights3 = mutate(flights, tm = paste0(hour, ":", minute, ":00")); flights3$tm <- round_hms(as_hms(flights3$tm), 60*60)` works. So it's not the code per se; it's the combination of your data and the code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer
One file looks like

Comment: structure(list(Date = c("2018-05-02", "2018-05-02", "2018-05-03", 
"2018-05-03", "2018-05-03", "2018-05-03", "2018-05-03", "2018-05-03", 
"2018-05-03", "2018-05-03", "2018-05-03", "2018-05-03", "2018-05-03", 
"2018-05-03", "2018-05-03"), Time = c("04:55:53", "06:41:04", 
"00:37:58", "06:36:14", "06:51:13", "07:09:30", "07:36:44", "07:45:58", 
"11:21:46", "12:45:10", "13:45:10", "14:45:11", "15:45:11", "16:45:11", 
"17:45:11"), users_holding = c(47, 47, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 
49, 49, 49, 49, 50, 51, 51)), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, it was a code issue. Sorry. Sigh.

You call the dataset with the list of datasets using an iterator. However when you wrote `st_datasets$Time` there's no iterator—and it won't work if you add one there.

You can still loop or you can vectorize. I've provided both methods.

#### Using vectorization

```
updt = lapply(1:length(st_datasets),
              function(i){
                st_datasets[[i]]$Time <- round_hms(as_hms(st_datasets[[i]]$Time), 60*60)
                st_datasets[[i]]
              })
```

#### Using a `for` loop

```
upper = list()
for(i in 1:length(st_datasets)){
  st_ds = st_datasets[[i]]
  st_ds$Time = round_hms(as_hms(st_ds$Time), 60*60)
  upper[[i]] <- st_ds
}
upper
```